# Correct way of using multiple ConnectionPool(s)

Tags: scala, jdbc, scalikejdbc

In my application, I have to interact (read-only) with multiple `MySQL` DBs one-by-one. For each DB, I need a certain no of connections. Interactions with a DB do not occur in a *single stretch*: I query the DB, take some time processing the results, again query the DB, again process the result and so on.

Each one of these interactions require *multiple connections* [**I fire multiple queries concurrently**], hence I need a `ConnectionPool` that spawns when I start interacting with the DB and lives until I'm done with all queries to that DB (including the interim time intervals when I'm not querying, only processing the results).

---

I'm able to successfully create a `ConnectionPool` with desired no of connections and obtain the `implicit session` as shown below

```
def createConnectionPool(poolSize: Int): DBSession = {
 implicit val session: AutoSession.type = AutoSession

 ConnectionPool.singleton(
   url = "myUrl",
   user = "myUser",
   password = "***",
   settings = ConnectionPoolSettings(initialSize = poolSize)
 )

 session
}
```

I then pass this `implicit session` throughout the methods where I need to interact with DB. That ways, I'm able to fire `poolSize` no of queries *concurrently* using this `session`. Fair enough.

```
def methodThatCallsAnotherMethod(implicit session: DBSession): Unit = {
  ...
  methodThatInteractsWithDb
  ...
}

def methodThatInteractsWithDb(implicit session: DBSession): Unit = {
  ...
  getResultsParallely(poolSize = 32, fetchSize = 2000000)
  ...
}

def getResultsParallely(poolSize: Int, fetchSize: Int)(implicit session: DBSession): Seq[ResultClass] = {
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize))

  val resultsSequenceFuture: Seq[Future[ResultClass]] = {
    (0 until poolSize).map { i =>
      val limit: Long = fetchSize
      val offset: Long = i * fetchSize

      Future(methodThatMakesSingleQuery(limit, offset))
    }
  }
  val resultsFutureSequence: Future[Seq[ResultClass]] = Future.sequence(resultsSequenceFuture)

  Await.result(resultsFuture, 2.minutes)
}
```

---

There are 2 problems with this technique:

1. My application is quite big and has many nested method calls, so passing `implicit session` through all methods like this (see below) isn't feasible.
2. In addition to the said interactions with different DBs one-by-one, I also need a *single connection* to another (fixed) DB throughout the lifetime of my entire application. This connection would be used to make a *small write operatio*n (*logging* the progress of my interactions with other DBs) after every few minutes. Therefore, I need multiple `ConnectionPool`s, one for each DB

---

From what I could make out of `ScalikeJdbc`'s [docs](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/connection-pool.html), I came up with following way of doing it that doesn't require me to pass the `implicit session` everywhere.

```
def createConnectionPool(poolName: String, poolSize: Int): Unit = {
  ConnectionPool.add(
    name = poolName,
    url = "myUrl",
    user = "myUser",
    password = "***",
    settings = ConnectionPoolSettings(initialSize = poolSize)
  )
}

def methodThatInteractsWithDb(poolName: String): Unit = {
  ...
  (DB(ConnectionPool.get(poolName).borrow())).readOnly { implicit session: DBSession =>
    // interact with DB
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Although this works, but I'm no longer able to *parallelize* the db-interaction. This behaviour is obvious since I'm using the `borrow()` method, that gets a *single connection* from the *pool*. This, in turn, makes me wonder why that `AutoSession` thing worked earlier: why was I able to fire multiple queries simultaneously using a single `implicit session`? And if that thing worked, then why doesn't this work? But I find no examples of how to obtain a `DBSession` from a `ConnectionPool` that supports multiple connections.

---

To sum up, I have 2 problems and 2 solutions: one for each problem. But I need a single (commmon) solution that solves both the problems.

`ScalikeJdbc`'s limited docs aren't offering a lot of help and blogs / articles on `ScalikeJdbc` are practically non-existent.
Please suggest the correct way / some work-around.

---

Framework versions

- `Scala 2.11.11`
- `"org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc" % "3.2.0"`

Comment: Here's the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalikejdbc-users-group/zIWc-lIEMvg) to my post in `ScalikeJdbc`'s `Google User Group` on this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [**@Dennis Hunziker**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50077994/3679900), I was able to figure out [the correct way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127994/3679900) to release connections borrowed from `ScalikeJdbc`'s `ConnectionPool`. It can be done as follows:

```
import scalikejdbc.{ConnectionPool, using}
import java.sql.Connection

using(ConnectionPool.get("poolName").borrow()) { (connection: Connection) =>
    // use connection (only once) here
}
// connection automatically returned to pool
```

With this, now I'm able to parallelize interaction with the pool.

---

To solve my problem of managing several `ConnectionPool`s and using connections across several `class`es, I ended up writing a `ConnectionPoolManager`, complete code for which can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/be8dd985c7578f4e6760a20c8cec0a9a). By offloading the tasks of

- creating pools
- borrowing connections from pools
- removing pools

to a `singleton` object that I could use anywhere across my project, I was able to clear a lot of clutter and eliminated the need pass `implicit session` across chain of methods.

---

**EDIT-1**

While I've already [linked](https://gist.github.com/y2k-shubham/be8dd985c7578f4e6760a20c8cec0a9a) the complete code for `ConnectionPoolManager`, here's a quick hint of how you can go about it

Following method of `ConnectionPoolManager` lets you borrow connections from `ConnectionPool`s

```
def getDB(dbName: String, poolNameOpt: Option[String] = None): DB = {
  // create a pool for db (only) if it doesn't exist
  addPool(dbName, poolNameOpt)

  val poolName: String = poolNameOpt.getOrElse(dbName)
  DB(ConnectionPool.get(poolName).borrow())
}
```

Thereafter, throughout your code, you can use the above method to borrow connections from pools and make your queries

```
def makeQuery(dbName: String, poolNameOpt: Option[String]) = {
  ConnectionPoolManager.getDB(dbName, poolNameOpt).localTx { implicit session: DBSession =>
    // perform ScalikeJdbc SQL query here
  }
}
```