# Release a Connection borrowed from ConnectionPool

Tags: scala, connection-pooling, scalikejdbc

`ScalikeJDBC's` `ConnectionPool` [docs page](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/connection-pool.html) says:

---

> **Borrowing Connections**
>
> Simply just call `#borrow` method.

```
import scalikejdbc._
val conn: java.sql.Connection = ConnectionPool.borrow()
val conn: java.sql.Connection = ConnectionPool('named).borrow()
```

> Be careful. The connection object should be released by yourself.

---

However there's no mention of how to do it.

I can always do `Connection.close()` but by '*releasing*' `Connection`,
I understand that I'm supposed to **return the `Connection` back to the `ConnectionPool`** and not *close* it (otherwise the purpose of having a `ConnectionPool` would be defied).

---

My doubts are:

1. In general, what does '*releasing*' a `Connection` (that has been borrowed from `ConnectionPool`) mean?
2. In `ScalikeJDBC`, how do I 'release' a `Connection` *borrowed* from `ConnectionPool`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `close` is fine. As per the Oracle docs: `Closing a connection instance that was obtained from a pooled connection does not close the physical database connection.`. The `DBConnection` in scalikejdbc just wraps the `java.sql.Connection` and delegates calls to `close`. The usual way of doing this with scalikejdbc is with the `using` function which is essentially an implementation of Java's try-with-resources.

See [Closing JDBC Connections in Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938517/closing-jdbc-connections-in-pool) for a similar discussion on JDBC.

Comment: While I've added an answer specific to `ScalikeJdbc`, I'm accepting this answer because it is generic and uncovers the underlying details of `JDBC` *Connection-Pooling*

Answer (score 1):

Upon a second look into the [docs](http://scalikejdbc.org/documentation/connection-pool.html), `ScalikeJdbc` does provide a **`using`** method implementing the **loan-pattern** that automatically returns the `connection` to the `ConnectionPool`.

So you can *borrow* a *connection*, use it, and return it to the *pool* as follows:

```
import scalikejdbc.{ConnectionPool, using}
import java.sql.Connection

using(ConnectionPool.get("poolName").borrow()) { (connection: Connection) =>
    // use connection (only once) here
}
// connection automatically returned to pool
```